# How to disable default error logger in Go-Gorm

Tags: mysql, go, error-handling, go-gorm

I am using GORM with MySQL, I have encountered and handled the error `Error 1062: Duplicate entry`. The problem is that it's still printed to the console.

Code in `gym/models/auth.go:49`:

```golang
func AddAuth(username, password string) error {
    passwordHash, err := auth.HashPassword(password, argon2Conf)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    userAuth := Auth{
        Username: username,
        Password: passwordHash,
    }
    return db.Create(&userAuth).Error
}
```

I am handling the error in the handler function:

```golang
func SignUpHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var form user
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&form); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    if err := models.AddAuth(form.Username, form.Password); err == nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "you are signed in"})
    } else {
        // I think I have handled the sql error here
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "sign in failed"})
    }
}
```

When I send a `POST` request, the error is correctly handled and I get the correct response with `{"error": "sign in failed"}`. But the console still prints this error message:

```
(/...../gym/models/auth.go:49) 
[2019-04-28 23:37:06]  Error 1062: Duplicate entry '123123' for key 'username' 
[GIN] 2019/04/28 - 23:37:06 | 400 |  136.690908ms |             ::1 | POST     /signup
```

I am confused since I handled the error but it still gets printed. How to prevent this error from getting printed to the error log? Or am I handle the error correct?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

UPDATE: for gorm `v2`:

Use the [`Logger`](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Log-Levels) in `gorm.Config`:

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
  Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent),
})
```

---

For gorm `v1`:

Use [db.LogMode](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm?hide=1&import-graph=#DB.LogMode) to silence the default error logger.

> LogMode set log mode, `true` for detailed logs, `false` for no log, default, will only print error logs.

`db.LogMode(false)` should do the job!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but just to add to the answer by `ifnotak`, you can log sql conditionally by controlling it through an environment variable. This can be handy during debugging.

```
gormConfig := &gorm.Config{}
if !logSql {
    // I use an env variable LOG_SQL to set logSql to either true or false.
    gormConfig.Logger = logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent)
}
db, err := gorm.Open(dialector, gormConfig)
```